# How do you parse a string at the beginning of every line of text in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to format text to be displayed in the Courier font and I'd like to enter 18 spaces at the beginning of each line so that they line up with other columns already present on the page.

My text is:

```
12 Something Street
1234 Ave
City, State Zip
Country
```

ideally I'd like:

```
                  12 Something Street
                  1234 Ave
                  City, State Zip
                  Country
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
$stuff = "12 Something Street
1234 Ave
City, State Zip
Country";

$stuff2 = str_replace("\n", "                  \n", $stuff);
```

Alternatively you could also use `str_pad`

```
$stuff2 = str_pad($stuff, 18, " ", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score 0):

what if you change the font size later?  use css.

You can do 
`$foo = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".%foo`;

really bad idea though - use css, specifically padding and/or margin.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display it in html:

```
$input='12 Something Street
1234 Ave
City, State Zip
Country';

$stringInput = explode( "\n" ,$input);

foreach( $stringInput as $item)
{
    echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' ,$item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Tested and Works**

```
<?php
$str=<<<EOD

12 Something Street
1234 Ave
City, State Zip
Country
EOD;
$string = "<font face='courier'>$str</font>";
$strL = explode( "\r" ,$string );

$i=0;
foreach($strL as $line)
{
    //echo str_pad($line, 18, "D",STR_PAD_LEFT);
    echo str_repeat("&nbsp;", 18).$line;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

OUTPUT:

[image]